# Publishing a Google Apps Script Library

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-libraries

I'm a little bit confused about how the new libraries are supposed to be published.

I create what I think is a very cool and useful library for Google Apps Scripts.

[google_api_client](https://docs.google.com/macros/library/versions/d/M5CBUAHRgCJ4cr1RnR_DeLHqm4_t7cCky)

But I don't know where I can publish this so others can enjoy and provide some feedback. I notice that I can publish my script as a template but I believe this will allow others to import my script and edit as they want, but if there are updates they would need to import my code once again.

the new library feature on the other hand require that the users find out about your application Id to import it on their projects.

As of today the only place where libraries are listed is the "[Notable Script Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/notable-script-libraries)" on the Google Developers site. But it's just for hand selected libraries from Google.

**So my questions here are:**

When should I publish my script as a template instead of publishing it as a library? They seem a little bit overlapping for me.

How are other people sharing their libraries? Is Google planning some kind of directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The existing Apps Script Gallery (Publish > Publish to Gallery) was created to share useful scripts with users, which should be fully built and ready to run.  There is currently no official gallery for libraries, which are targeted at other script developers. For the time being you could create a useful script that uses your library, and publish that the Script Gallery in order to gain visibility.

Comment: I've created a feature request to add a gallery for libraries, feel free to star it for updates. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1381